# Where to buy Sobranie cigarettes in Athens, Greece

Tags: greece, smoking, athens

I tried searching for Sobranie cigarettes in Athens, I searched the whole city center but nobody even knows what it is. Also tried looking it up on googles 'near me' function, but to no avail.
Does anyone know where could I get a pack of these in Athens?

Comment: I think this is a shopping question so it might be closed soon.

Comment: Wikipedia says `Sobranie is a Russian brand of cigarettes, currently owned and manufactured by Gallaher Group, a subsidiary of Japan Tobacco`. Are they typically available outside russia?

Comment: yeah, it's available around the world. Not sure why I can't find it in Greece. @BernhardDöbler

Comment: I believe there is a small number of companies that produce cigarettes and a lot of brands. Maybe this producer has a well established brand in greece and dont want to be his own competitor by introducing the russian brand.

Comment: My best guess is the airport taxfrees.